# .NET collections: How to get a new list from an existing list between start to end value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string list. I need to create a separate list based on all entries between a set of start and end values, including those start and end values, where there may be multiple such sequences.

```
var stringList = {
    "16a_Start", "test1", "test11", "16a_End",
    "15a_start", …, "15a_end",
    "16a_Start", "test2", "test22", "16a_End",
    "15a_start", …, "15a_end"
}
```

This should result in e.g.,

```
var 16aList = { 
    { "16a_Start", "test1", "test11", "16a_End" },
    { "16a_Start", "test2", "test22", "16a_End"}
}
```

Similarly for `15aList`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Offering some code that you're working with, even though it's not working, will make it easier for the community to identify where you're getting stuck, and offer more concrete suggestions on how to solve it.

Comment: I tried to read recursively but don't know how to achieve it

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the code you've tried? Also, must this be in LINQ? I'm not convinced you're going to get a very readable solution in LINQ, even if it's possible. It would be comparatively trivial to handle this via a `while` loop. Of course, you'll need to determine if there's any possibility of malformed data (e.g., unending sequences, overlapping sequences), and how to account for those.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I am getting data as list of objects which contains tags like "16a_start" Tag and "16a_end" tag data , this sequence don't have limit   need to convert as new object that is "16a" tags data as separate list object . I am fine with while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73071828/net-collections-how-to-get-a-new-list-from-an-existing-list-between-start-to-e#comment129057449_73071828)), you're likely going to find this more intuitive to solve via a `while` loop. That's because LINQ, like SQL, is optimized for set-based queries. By contrast, since this requires keeping track of the start and end position of the various segments, it's easier to solve with a procedural approach.

#### General Approach

The basic idea in the procedural approach is, given an array and a segment key (e.g., `16a`), to find the positions in the array that correspond to the start segment (e.g., `16a_Start`) and the end segment (e.g., `16a_end`), copy the data between those positions, and add them to an array of output. Once that's done, we'll repeat this, starting at the position of the end segment.

#### Implementation Details

To implement this, we can use the following methods built into the .NET base class library:

- **[`Array.IndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-6.0)** will allow us to get the position of the start or end segment, thus defining the range of any one block.
- **[`Array.Copy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-6.0)** will allow us to copy elements of the source array starting at the start segment, for the specified length of the segment.

#### Sample Code

Here's a rough example of how we might approach this. This isn't intended to be final code, but rather a proof-of-concept to get you started.

```
public string[][] ExtractSegment(string[] values, string segmentKey)
{
    var currentIndex        = 0;
    var output              = new List<String[]>();
    while (currentIndex >= 0)
    {
        var startIndex      = Array.IndexOf(values, $"{segmentKey}_Start", currentIndex);
        if (startIndex >= 0)
        {
            var endIndex    = Array.IndexOf(values, $"{segmentKey}_End", startIndex);
            var length      = endIndex-startIndex+1;
            var segment     = new string[length];
            Array.Copy(values, startIndex, segment, 0, length);
            output.Add(segment);
            currentIndex    = endIndex;
        }
        else 
        {
            currentIndex    = startIndex;
        }
    }
    return output.ToArray();
}
```

#### Testing

You can test this with the following:

```
string[] stringList = {
    "16a_Start", "test1", "test11", "16a_End",
    "15a_start", "test1", "test11", "15a_end",
    "16a_Start", "test2", "test22", "16a_End",
    "15a_start", "test1", "test11", "15a_end"
};
var 16a = ExtractSegment(stringList, "16a");
```

#### Limitations

This code assumes that there will *always* be a corresponding end segment (e.g., `16a_End`) for every start segment (e.g., `16a_Start`). It also assumes that these will be sequential; i.e., that the segments won't overlap. This may or may not be a valid assumption depending on how clean or reliable your data source is. The above code will give you a good foundation to work from, but a more robust, production ready implementation will include additional checks to validate the data integrity.

#### Conclusion

Note that there very well may be a clever use of LINQ to solve this—and, if I have some extra time, I'll put some thought into that. But my suspicion is that, even if there is, the procedural approach will be more straight-forward to read, and will be much easier to add code to handle possible issues with the data. Similarly, there are some syntactical shortcuts that could make the above code tidier, but the longer form makes it easier to read and reason through.